# How to click accept/consent/ok cookies button present in any website (generalize for any site) using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click accept/consent/ok/close (various pattern of acceptance) cookies button using python selenium webdriver, but unable to do so. Find my code snippet below and can this be generalize for any website?

```
driver.get("https://home.barclays")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Accept all cookies']"))).click()


driver.get("https://www.cisco.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't because every website is going to be different. You'd have to look at every website you are trying to automate and see if there is any pattern or locator that will work for them but it's unlikely you will find one.

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can do for the above mentioned 2 sites?